# socket inputstream issue in j2me (BB)

Tags: sockets, blackberry, java-me, xmpp

I am working on XMPP client for BB with JXA, but JXA api takes time to read from inputstream and through timeout error after 2 mins. I written seperate socket program in J2ME and executed in the BB simulator, it could exchange XML but the inputstream is not quitting from the while loop, gets hang in reading. Please see the below code..

```
class SocketThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {

          ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
          ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
          connDesc = connFact.getConnection("socket://xxxxxx.p1.im:5222");
          if (connDesc != null)
          {
              SocketConnection httpConn;
              httpConn = (SocketConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
              try
              {
                 InputStream is = httpConn.openInputStream();
                 OutputStream os = httpConn.openOutputStream();

                 String a = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><stream:stream to=\"xxxxx.p1.im\" xml:lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\">";

                 os.write(a.getBytes());

                 byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                 int len =0;
                            while ((len = is.read(b)) > 0) {


                                String str = new String(b);

                                 System.out.println("Server n: " + str);


                                 }

                  UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {
                          Dialog.alert("got response xml stream..: "  
                                        );
                      }
                   });
               } 
               catch (IOException e) 
               {
                 System.err.println("Caught IOException: " 
                      + e.getMessage());
               }
          }
    }
}
```

Above program not coming out of the loop unless until it timesout, please help me out to fix this issue to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A read timeout means no data arrived within the timeout period. Nothing else.

Your code is wrong in other ways however: you are assuming the read filled the buffer, and ignoring positive values of 'len' when constructing the String, so you are passing yourself junk.

Comment: Well the above code able to receive the xml streams from XMPP server, after reading two full xml stream still hanging on and its not quitting that is my problem.

Comment: "Your code is wrong in other ways" - to add to this - streams ALWAYS should be closed after usage. In your case the best place to put closing code is `finally` block (absent right now).

Comment: well guys, fixed the problem in BB, at the end of socket URL "deviceside=true" parameter is a must to have communicated checked the demo apps and got solved thnx for your help.

Comment: @Balaji so you got lucky. The code is still wrong for the reasons I stated.

Comment: My friend this is just sample snippet i pasted here, agree I pasted wrong code and you are a intelligent guy :)